# Exception when starting liberty server 16.0.0.4

Tags: websphere-liberty

*Noticed the below exception when starting websphere liberty server. 
 How can this be removed? Appreciate any help.
We have both javaee7 profile and webProfile-6.0 features installed.
The EAR application has one WAR file which uses jee6.0 / "3.0" web.xml*

```
Exception = java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Source = com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.InjectionProcessorManager.getAllDeclaredFields
probeid = 249
Stack Dump = java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.websphere.sdo.mediator.jdbc.ConnectionWrapper
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFieldsImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:833)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.InjectionProcessorManager.getAllDeclaredFields(InjectionProcessorManager.java:375)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.InjectionProcessorManager.processAnnotations(InjectionProcessorManager.java:216)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.processInjectionMetaData(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:514)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.osgi.internal.OSGiInjectionEngineImpl.processInjectionMetaData(OSGiInjectionEngineImpl.java:239)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.ReferenceContextImpl.processImpl(ReferenceContextImpl.java:633)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.ReferenceContextImpl.process(ReferenceContextImpl.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.osgi.internal.OSGiReferenceContextImpl.process(OSGiReferenceContextImpl.java:31)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationStart(WebApp.java:254)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1038)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6562)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:468)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler(DynamicVirtualHost.java:266)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler(DynamicVirtualHost.java:331)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl.discriminate(VirtualHostImpl.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:301)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:471)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:405)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:285)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:256)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.websphere.sdo.mediator.jdbc.ConnectionWrapper
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:499)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:282)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:846)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:825)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:477)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:805)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: Is there any old jar in classpath causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The SDO API (`com.ibm.websphere.sdo`) is not available in Liberty. Looks like you are trying to run some traditional WAS application on Liberty. You will have to change your application to make it runnable in Liberty.

I'd suggest to install WebSphere Application Migration Toolkit(free Eclipse plugin from Marketplace) and analyze your application.